# ¿Como puedo graficar en android ¡ datos obtenidos de mysql?

Tags: php, android, jsonobject

El codigó completo no se me permite publicar pero actualmente el código si utilizo un arreglo estatico si me grafica, pero al momento de querer introducir los datos obtenidos de mysql no me grafica.

```
//String[] axisData = new String[]{jsonObject.getString("hora")};
//int[] yAxisData = new int[]{(jsonObject.getInt("tension"))};
//int[] y2AxisData = new int[]{(jsonObject.getInt("ts"))};


String[] axisData = new String[]{"00:00", "01:00", "02:00", "03:00", "04:00", "05:00", "06:00", "07:00", "08:00", "09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00"};
int[] yAxisData = new int[]{40, 45, 50, 45, 50, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 65, 60};
int[] y2AxisData = new int[]{30, 35, 40, 35, 30, 35, 40, 45, 40, 35, 30, 35, 30};
```

Comment: Tu pregunta no es clara. Explica por favor qué es lo necesitas hacer, que es lo que no funciona, qué error da, si has verificado que los datos están llegando bien, cómo llegan los datos, con qué formato... etc. Pulsa en [edit]  para mejorar la pregunta. Si son datos sensibles los puedes cambiar por otros ficticios.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio , revisa por favor  [ask], debes especificar como los estas graficando, de otra forma es dificil saber lo que deseas, saludos.